# When do i start the casting?

Tags: android, casting, chromecast

Hi just want to cast an audio mp3 file by given url from my phone. in my Application i started the casting method when connection is established that means after calling of setSelection method and initialized the GoogleApiClient instance. but casting is not happen, whether am i doing correct way or not if not, then when do i start the casting. Please guide me to start the casting and their life cycles.
Thanks in Advance.

My Code Part is

```
private void setSelectedDevice(CastDevice device) {
    Log.d(Tag, "setSelectedDevice: " + device);
    mSelectedDevice = device;

    if (mSelectedDevice != null) {

        try {
            disconnectApiClient();
            connectApiClient();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.w(Tag, "Exception while connecting API client", e);
            disconnectApiClient();
        }
    } else {
        if (mApiClient != null) {
            if (mApiClient.isConnected()) {
                if (mRemoteMediaPlayer != null && isPlaying) {
                    mRemoteMediaPlayer.pause(mApiClient);
                }
            }
            disconnectApiClient();
        }
        mMediaRouter.selectRoute(mMediaRouter.getDefaultRoute());
    }
}

private void connectApiClient() {
    Cast.CastOptions apiOptions = Cast.CastOptions.builder(mSelectedDevice,
            mCastListener).build();
    mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Cast.API, apiOptions)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(mConnectionCallbacks)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(mConnectionFailedListener)
            .build();

    // Start the casting when connected the route device  // here i am start the casting....

    if(songURL != null){
        Log.d(Tag, "Current casting url:" + songURL);
        isPlaying = false;
        firstTimeCasting = true;
        SynchwithChromeCast(songURL);    // here load the song url with remoteplayer
        //Play(songURL);
    }
}

private void SynchwithChromeCast(String file){
    if(firstTimeCasting){
        firstTimeCasting = false;

        try {

            Log.e("Play Testing", "mRemoteMediaPlayer is play");

            if(firstTimeCasting){
                firstTimeCasting = false;

            //mRemoteMediaPlayer = new RemoteMediaPlayer();

            isPlaying = true;

            MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(
                    MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK);
            mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ALBUM_ARTIST,
                    "" +singers.getText().toString());
            mediaMetadata.putString(mediaMetadata.KEY_ALBUM_TITLE,
                    "" +songTitle.getText().toString());
            MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(file)
                    .setContentType("audio/mp3")
                    .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                    .setMetadata(mediaMetadata).build();
            mRemoteMediaPlayer
                    .load(mApiClient, mediaInfo, true)
                    .setResultCallback(
                            new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {

                                @Override
                                public void onResult(
                                        MediaChannelResult result) {
                                    if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                        Log.d(Tag, "Media loaded Successfully" + result.getStatus());
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Log.d(Tag, "Media loaded Not Successfully" + result.getStatus());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
            }

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(Tag, e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e(Tag, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
// activate play button
    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // disable the button
            if (PlusUtilities.isInternetConnected()) {
                play.setEnabled(false);

                // if mediaplayer is in pause state
                if (mp != null & !mp.isPlaying()) {

                    mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition());
                    playSong(false);
                    updateProgressBar();
// Interact with Chrome-cast while play/pause    ////////

                    //reset
                    firstTimeCasting = false;

                    isPlaying = true;
                    Play(songURL);   // Play or Pause the chromecast receiver
                    }
                    else if (mp != null) {

                    playSong(true);
                    //if(songURL != null)
                    isPlaying = false;
                        Play(songURL);
                }

    });
private void Play(String file) {

    if (mp != null && isPlaying) {
        if (mApiClient != null) {
            Log.e("Play **********", mApiClient.isConnected() + " ++++++++Status");
            if (mApiClient.isConnected()) {
                if (mRemoteMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mRemoteMediaPlayer.pause(mApiClient);
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (mp != null && !isPlaying && !firstTimeCasting) {
        if (mApiClient != null) {
            if (mApiClient.isConnected()) {
                if (mRemoteMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mRemoteMediaPlayer.play(mApiClient);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at a number of samples that we have on [GitHub](https://github.com/googlecast) to see how the flow should be; it is an asynchronous set of calls, so

- After calling connect, you wait for onConnected to be called, that signals a connection
- Then you load the "application" using the app id that you were assigned on Developer Console or the default app id
- When application is launched successfully, you then load the media and then you can play or do as you wish.

Read our [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, so i have to load the media on receiver side after launched receiver app successfully that means i should call SynchwithChromeCast(songURL)method in public void onResult(ApplicationConnectionResult result) { if(status.isSuccess()} is correct?

Comment: something like that, and launching of app should be done in the onConnected callback. Look at https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender, that definitely helps.

Comment: Yes correct, hereafter i will load media in onConnection callback if status is success.and one more thing, Pls look on my code in  SynchwithChromeCast(songURL) method is there correct code to load the mp3 songs by song url for casting? Kindly tell me if it is anything wrong or missing some thing.

Comment: Siva, I am not going to review your code and correct that for you; if you want to continue developing for Chromecast, you need to invest time in reading docs and running samples to familiarize yourself.

Comment: ok Ali NAddaf, i will check on my code by testing and improve my code as ur suggestion for start casting on which place. really helped. now am getting clear idea in casting concepts. Thanks for ur support.

Comment: Hi, I have checked now but no luck still it's not cast nothing